# Large drives and FileVault/TimeMachine on Mountain Lion

Tags: time-machine, filevault

Trying to use a 3TB disk for my backups, still running into what seems to be a known issue with "block sizes". When will this be fixed or how can I fix it myself before a downstream update?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: MediaKit reports block size error, usually caused by not being a multiple of 512...

Comment: Can you please provide additional information about the issue? What are you trying to do, what is the result? If it's an error message, a screenshot or a log extract would help as well.